# How to explode integer values

Tags: php

I've a variable

```
$message_days = 45; 62; 35;
```

I want to explode the variable with terminator `;`. How to explode it?

Comment: I think you need to elaborate on the whole numbers-separated-by-semicolons thing. Where do they come from? Do you have avariable which contains those values as a string, or as an integer array? If those numbers exist raw in the php file as they are now, they're gone for good. It's as though you have 3 lines, the first assigning a single integer and the other lines no-op-ing.

Comment: This line remind me my mistake (Do you have avariable which contains those values as a string, or as an integer array? If those numbers exist raw in the php file as they are now, they're gone for good.). Thanks for your help. Its done.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you can't assign the INT values like this on a single variable

```
$message_days = 45; 62; 35;
```

because `$message_days` returns only `45` not the whole. And second thing you `explode()` function is used to Split a string by string. So you have to make the string of these values like, Assume `$_POST['text_field'] = 45; 62; 35;`

`$message_days = "45; 62; 35;";`
or
`$message_days = settype( $_POST["text_field"], "string")`

then use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function.

### UPDATE:

as you said you need int value in array then use this code that return the **Integer value in array**:

```
//$message_days = "45;62;35";
$message_days = settype( $_POST["text_field"], "string")

OR

$message_days = "'" . $_POST["text_field"] . "'";

$output = array_map('intval', explode(';', $message_days));

var_dump( $output );
```

http://codepad.org/LghB9tng

Comment: $message_days = "45;62;35"; is actually integer values like this $message_days = 45;62;35; how to add quotes around my values the input is coming from user via text field like this 45; 32; 64.

Comment: @user2727841 can you show the part of the code where you assigned the `$message_days = 45;62;35;`

Comment: Sorry can not show you the code. The value is coming from text field and I explode it like this $message_days = @explode(";", $message_days);.

Comment: @user2727841 so what you're really after is just the `array_map('intval'...` part? Or do you want to un-explode, i.e. join the values?

Comment: @user2727841 i just use a rocket sense to convert your text field into string and hope this works for you, i have used `settype()` that converts your values into string.

Answer (score 1):

If your variable is a string you can do it like this

```
$message_days = '45; 62; 35;';
$arr = explode(';',$message_days);
print_r($arr);
```

if you are using it as a integer then you cannot do that. 
`$message_days = 45; 62; 35;`
 the value of 
`$message_days`
 will be 45 if you echo `$message_days;`.Since its 45 if you explode it you will get only one value in the array which will be 45.

Comment: I can not use it into string. I've to use it as a integer Its my application requirment.

Comment: this is invalid `$message_days = 45; 62; 35;` - it will throw a php error.

Comment: No it wont @LatheesanKanes.

Comment: $message_days = "45;62;35"; is actually integer values like this $message_days = 45;62;35; how to add quotes around my values the input is coming from user via text field like this 45; 32; 64.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$message_days = "45;62;35";
$output = explode(";",$message_days);
print_r($output);
?>
```

Comment: $message_days = "45;62;35"; is actually integer values like this $message_days = 45;62;35; how to add quotes around my values the input is coming from user via text field like this 45; 32; 64.

Answer (score 0):

If $message_days  as your input is a String, use

```
$result = explode( ';', $message_days);
```

to explode it, as suggested.

Then iterate the result and convert each String to a integer like this:

```
foreach( $result as $position => $value )
{
 $result[$pos] = intval( $value);
}
```

Your result is an array of integers.

Comment: $message_days = "45;62;35"; is actually integer values like this $message_days = 45;62;35; how to add quotes around my values the input is coming from user via text field like this 45; 32; 64.

Comment: If the input comes from a user `<input>` it should be transmitted as a String shouldn't it? As the name '_text_ field' already suggests...
How dou you recieve the value anyway? Via `$_POST` or `$_GET`? Then it definitely is a string.

Comment: I've class which get the input and maniplate it in function I've two functions one get only integer and second get string. I used integer so I've changed it into string problem solve. Thanks for your help.